# Needing a component similar to JTabbedPane

Tags: java, components, jtabbedpane

I'm looking for a component like "JTabbedPane" in which I can design each tab separately and easily but I don't want the little square buttons with tab names in runtime! Instead, I want to activate each tab panel in my code. In fact, I want to have multiple "JPanel"s with same size and location (they have complete overlap) and I set visibility of each them manually in my code but the most importing thing is that I want to design each panel as easy as possible (like clicking on the tab names in design-time).

Comment: what's wrong in editing different JPanels?

Comment: The JPanels have overlapping completely; so making each one on top of others is not as easy as selecting them!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) here to create your own overlapping panels as you have described. The visibility of each panel can be programmatically changed.

Comment: yeah that was my first reaction. CardLayout. But what's with this guy talking about "designing each JPanel as easy as possible"

Comment: Not sure but it should be easy enough to create the panels to add to the container using this layout.

Comment: yeah i got confused with his sentence "designing each JPanel as easy as possible" Like at design time(probably with drag+drop)

Comment: Yes! The problem is in design-time and the space these JPanels require is the point!